# How can I utilize an Emacs macro which has already been compiled?

Tags: python, emacs, compilation, lisp-macros

I am attempting to modify the python major mode to work slightly differently. Specifically, I would like to change [python-indent-region](http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/lh/emacs/trunk/annotate/head:/lisp/progmodes/python.el#L1061). I believe I have figured out what change I need to make (it involves changing line #1070 to be `(beginning-of-line)`). I have tried to change it like that by copying the function into my init.el file and changing that line. However, when I then try to use that function I get the following error:

```
Lisp error: (void-function python-rx)
```

I've done some research and it looks like the issue is that `python-rx` is actually defined using a `defmacro` in python.el. Since python.el is distributed with emacs it is already compiled and seems to reside in `/usr/share/emacs/24.5/lisp/progmodes/python.elc`. I was reading about macro compilation [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Compiling-Macros.html) and as I understand it, the macro has been compiled so when I try to reference it it's no longer available.

This comes down to two questions:

1. Am I correct in my above understanding?
2. How can I accomplish my goal of redefining this function to be mostly the same, despite the fact that it relies on the macro `python-rx`?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What changes do you want to make?

Comment: @jenesaisquoi That didn't work, `python-rx` was still undefined. I figured out another way to solve my issue.

I wanted python's region indentation function to indent the first line of the region even if point was in the middle of the line. I was able to get this behavior by adding a hook to set `indent-region-function` to nil when entering `elpy-mode`. This caused the `indent-according-to-mode` function to be run on each line in the region.